# Image formula field render issue

Tags: formula, static-resources, images, if, image-formula

I have a formula that is rendering a static resource based on checkboxes on my Contact record. The issue I am seeing is that when the image loads, it appears super tiny - the static resource is not this small. It appears the only way to fix this is to scroll down in the browser so the Compact Layout fields become hidden, and then scroll back up to render the image again.

Has anyone seen this behavior before, or know what could be causing it??

- Currently on Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Winter 20 Production

[image: Image rendering small on load]

[image: Image renders normally after scrolling down and back up]

Code Sample below:

```
 IF(
AND(Board_Member__c = TRUE,
Deceased__c = TRUE),
IMAGE("/resource/1565661725000/Board_Member_Deceased", "Board Member Deceased"),



IF(
AND(Board_Member__c = TRUE,
Contact_Alert__c= TRUE),
IMAGE("/resource/1565661531000/Alert_Board_Member", "Alert Board Member"),


IF(Board_Member__c = TRUE,
IMAGE("/resource/1565661795000/Board_Member_Logo?", "BM"),

IF(
AND(
Deceased__c = TRUE,
Contact_Alert__c = TRUE), IMAGE("/resource/1565661904000/Contact_Alert_Deceased", "Contact Alert Deceased"),

IF(
AND(Board_Member__c = TRUE,
Deceased__c = TRUE),
IMAGE("/resource/1565625538000/Board_Member_Deceased", "Board Member Deceased"),

IF(Contact_Alert__c = TRUE, IMAGE("/resource/1565661631000/Alert_Image", "Alert"),



IF(Deceased__c = TRUE, IMAGE("/resource/1565662013000/Deceased", "Deceased"),

IF(DoNotCall = TRUE, IMAGE("/resource/1565643021000/Do_Not_Contact","Do Not Contact"),

null))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen this but... you can set the image height and width.

`enter code here`IMAGE(image_url, alternate_text [, height, width])